# How to name std::thread on Mac OS X in C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, c++11

I want to name a thread, but unfortunately the `pthread_setname_np()` on Mac works only inside current thread.

Then I do the wrapper around `std::thread` with a following constructor:

```
template <class F, class ... Args>
Thread::Thread(const char* name, F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  thread_ = std::thread([name, f, args...]() {
    pthread_setname_np(name);
    f(args...);
  });
}
```

But it doesn't work with class methods:

```
error: called object type '<complex type>' is not a function or function pointer
f(args...);
^
```

In the code like this:

```
threads_.emplace_back("Name", &Aggregator<T>::DoPop, this, some_arg);
```

---

What is a proper way to wrap the `std::thread` and set the thread name, preserving the whole interface excepting the `name` argument in the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::mem_fn` to call a member function. The first argument in args has to be the pointer to the member object.

Example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

template <class F, class ... Args>
std::thread thread_factory(const char* name, F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  return std::thread([=]{
    pthread_setname_np(name);
    auto fun = std::mem_fn(f);
    fun(args...);
  });
}

struct test {
  int t(int val) {
    return val;
  }
};

int main() {
  test t;
  auto b = thread_factory("name", &test::t, &t, 5);
  b.join();
}
```

Comment: Works for me, what is you compiler? `Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)`

Comment: The version is the same - have you tried it on some class method?

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem, i will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

you have to bind your member function to a class instance. here's your function presented slightly differently with a (working) test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

template <class F, class ... Args>
std::thread launch_named_thread(const char* name, F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return std::thread([name, f, args...]() {
        pthread_setname_np(name);
        f(args...);
    });
}

struct myclass
{
    void thread_loop(int i)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};

auto main() -> int
{
    myclass x;
    auto t = launch_named_thread("hello", std::bind(&myclass::thread_loop, &x, 6));
    // this could be:
    // auto t = launch_named_thread("hello", std::bind(&myclass::thread_loop, &x, std::placeholders::_1), 6);
    // the difference is subtle. i'll leave it to you to work out why
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```